# How to batch delete all elements matching an xpath?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

What is an elegant way to delete all elements in a DOM that match a certain xpath, *without* looping through the result set to delete them one by one?

Comment: There is no native shortcut method without using libraries or helper functions that do the looping for you

Comment: Agree with @charlietfl. Curious to know why  you don't want to use loop?

Comment: @supputuri I already know how to achieve this by looping. I was curious whether a more elegant way, with less code and perhaps better performance, exists.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it basically with jquery.
for example delete all anchor link which is under the div > p

```
$("div > p > a").remove()
```